# Unable to scrape Kubernetes nodes with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am currently using Prometheus to scrape Kubernetes components. I am able to scrape pods only and not nodes. I followed the official documentation to write config file. I added "prometheus.io/scrape=true" annotation to the nodes. Still it is not working. What other notations should be there. This is the config file.

```
- job_name: "kubernetes-nodes"

# The URL scheme with which to fetch metrics from targets.
scheme: https

# Optional TLS configuration.
tls_config:
# Disable validation of the server certificate.
  insecure_skip_verify: true

kubernetes_sd_configs:
- api_servers:
  - https://kubernetes.default.svc
  role: node

relabel_configs:
- action: labelmap
  regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
- target_label: __address__
  replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
  regex: (.+)
  target_label: __metrics_path__
  replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics
```

I went through the prometheus logs and this is the error-

`level=error msg="Cannot initialize nodes collection: unable to list Kubernetes nodes: unable to query any API servers: Get https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/nodes: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" source="node.go:124"`

I followed this example configuration file https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml

Comment: Please elaborate on what's "not working"; particularly on what are the steps you took to debug the cluster. What is the "official tutorial" you followed? Share the link. Also, what are the manifests you used to deploy Prometheus? To scrape the nodes, Prometheus requires `node-exporter`. Also, `kube-state-metrics` is needed to scrape `kube-apiserver`. Without this information, help can't be rendered.

Comment: @EugeneChow I have updated about the logs.  I dint use node-exporter.

Comment: What you deployed isn't sufficient and you'll have a really hard time deploying the dependencies by hand. I suggest using prometheus-operator instead https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/. Their repo has convenient scripts to auto-deploy the entire cluster. Also, the `certificate signed by unknown authority` error means that Prometheus wasn't provided with kubernetes' CA. It's needed for Prom to establish a HTTPS connection to kube-apiserver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in scraping node exporter from Prometheus running on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215896/error-in-scraping-node-exporter-from-prometheus-running-on-kubernetes)