# Error in scraping node exporter from Prometheus running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am running a Prometheus pod on Kubernetes cluster. I have a `node-exporter` installed on an instance in Openstack. It is running fine. I added its configuration in prometheus config file. After reloading, the target node-exporter shows up but its status is Down and the error is `context deadline exceeded`. I tried increasing the`scrape-timeout` but it also dint work. Rest all targets are working fine and are `UP`. I tried to ping the target endpoint from inside container and it is also fine. But unfortunately, there is no `curl` or `wget` inside container to check the metrics endpoint. This is the config file snippet.

```
- job_name: "node-exporter"
  metrics_path: '/metrics/'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.248.243:9100']
```

I checked the prometheus logs and here they are.

```
time="2017-07-20T12:53:37Z" level=info msg="Checkpointing in-memory metrics and chunks..." source="persistence.go:549" 
time="2017-07-20T12:53:44Z" level=info msg="Done checkpointing in-memory metrics and chunks in 6.631738129s." source="persistence.go:573" 
time="2017-07-20T12:54:18Z" level=error msg="Watch nodes unexpectedly closed: EOF" source="node.go:162" 
time="2017-07-20T12:58:44Z" level=info msg="Checkpointing in-memory metrics and chunks..." source="persistence.go:549" 
time="2017-07-20T12:58:50Z" level=info msg="Done checkpointing in-memory metrics and chunks in 6.154427033s." source="persistence.go:573" 
time="2017-07-20T12:58:58Z" level=error msg="Watch pods unexpectedly closed: EOF" source="pod.go:169" 
time="2017-07-20T13:01:13Z" level=info msg="Loading configuration file /etc/prometheus/conf/prometheus.yml" source="main.go:247" 
time="2017-07-20T13:01:42Z" level=error msg="Watch pods unexpectedly closed: EOF" source="pod.go:169"
```

My Kubernetes version is 1.6.4.

Comment: I just realized that the metrics endpoint is not responding from outside. Why? I have no clue.

Comment: Responding from the outside of what? And I think you will want to run another pod inside k8s that _does_ have curl in it so you can run more experiments

Comment: Separate from that, are you aware that prometheus will [auto discover openstack things](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#<openstack_sd_config>)? We use the [kubernetes one](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config>) and it works really well; thus, you may have more success letting prometheus find that node than inputting a static target for it